# How to count the first element in a list with 2-tuples of strings?

Tags: python, list, dictionary, count

I am trying to define a function `count_first_names` that input a list of names, 2-tuple of strings as in `(first_name,last_name)` and that returns a dictionary whose keys are first names and the values are the number of times that the first name appears on the list.

For example, take the first 5 presidents of the U.S.,

```
presidents = [("George","Washington"),
              ("John","Adams"),
              ("Thomas","Jefferson"),
              ("James", "Madison"),
              ("James", "Monroe"),]
```

Then, I would like to see:

```
count_first_names(presidents)
{'George':1, 'John':1, 'Thomas':1, 'James':2}
```

First, I created an empty dictionary, and took the first element of each tuple in the list. But I am not sure what to do next. Please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To count multiple items use the [Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
collections.Counter(p[0] for p in presidents)
# Counter({'James': 2, 'George': 1, 'John': 1, 'Thomas': 1})
```

The result is a `dict` subclass.

Answer (score 2):

try this code:

```
presidents = [("George","Washington"),
              ("John","Adams"),
              ("Thomas","Jefferson"),
              ("James", "Madison"),
              ("James", "Monroe"),]
count_dict = {}
for ele in presidents:
    count_dict[ele[0]] = count_dict.get(ele[0],0) + 1

print(count_dict)
```

output is:

```
{'George': 1, 'John': 1, 'Thomas': 1, 'James': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to try comprehension:

```py
{firstName:sum(item[0]==firstName for item in presidents) for firstName in set(item[0] for item in presidents)}
```

**OUTPUT**

```py
Out[7]: {'Thomas': 1, 'John': 1, 'George': 1, 'James': 2}
```

Comment: This is inefficient (quadratic complexity).